# Shifting ArrayList elements to the right

Tags: java, arraylist

Full disclosure this was an interview question that I didn't get right. Here's the question:

```
    /*
     * If you have an integer that is too large to be stored as a built-in type
     * like an int or double, you can represent it as an array of single digits.
     * Write a function that will increment such a number by 1. For example, the
     * number 1,235 would be represented as [1, 2, 3, 5] in an array. The
     * function should take the array [1, 2, 3, 5] as input and return the array
     * [1, 2, 3, 6].
     */
```

I have an ArrayList with each element representing the digit in a base-10 number. I want to create a method to increment the number, and then output that incremented number. So I have this:

```
package start;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class InputArray {

    private ArrayList<Integer> value;

    public InputArray(ArrayList<Integer> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


    private ArrayList<Integer> returnBigNum() {

        ArrayList<Integer> input = this.value;
//      input.set(0,0) // this won't work

        for (int i = input.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            Integer temp = input.get(i);

            temp++;

            if (temp.equals(10)) {
                input.set(i, 0);
            } else {
                input.set(i, temp);
                return input;
            }
        }
        return input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InputArray ia1 = new InputArray(new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
            add(3);add(9);add(9);add(9);add(9);
        }});

        InputArray ia2 = new InputArray(new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
            add(9);add(9);add(9);
        }});

        ArrayList<Integer> result1 = ia1.returnBigNum();
        out.println(result1);

        ArrayList<Integer> result2 = ia2.returnBigNum();
        out.println(result2);
    }

}
```

The problem I have is with input that is all 9s, like 999, 9999, 999999, etc.
With input = 999, I end up with 000.

So, a quick solution would be to add one element in the zeroeth place at the beginning of the method, then you have final element to iterate over. But the question is then, how do I shift all the elements to the right? And if that is too much computational effort, what is better workaround?

To shift things to the right, is this all that is necessary?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
void    add(int index, E element) 
          Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.

isn't that computationally expensive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `0` to the start of the list simply with:

```
//      the element to add
//           |
//           V
input.add(0, 0);
//        ^
//        |
// the index to add it at
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) is the documentation for this overload of the `add` method.

Comment: yeah, this works, but maybe not the most efficient thing

Comment: @AlexMills It's the most efficient way to add things to the start of an ArrayList, which is what you asked.

Answer (score 4):

Store the numbers in reverse order, that is, index 0 is for 10^0, index 1 is for 10^1 and so on. For example 1,235 would be `[5, 3, 2, 1]`.

PS: The interview question is nonsense. `BigInteger` is what you have to use.

Comment: ha yeah it was a Google interview

Comment: @AlexMills Still makes no sense to me to reinvent the wheel.